# How can I bind my options to a dropdown while using bindingHandlers in knockoutJS

Tags: jquery, razor, knockout.js

I can't get options in dropdown

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.SomeArray, selectedOptions: cities, optionsText: 'LocDescription', selectPicker: {}"></select>
```

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.options = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {},
  update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {}
}
```

Comment: Please be careful to format the code in your questions properly. This was unreadable before I edited.

Answer (score 0):

`options` is a default binding handler and you've now overwritten it with one that doesn't do anything. Just remove your binding handler and it should be fine.

Comment: it is not working.if i remove options how can it work